# Jasmine unit testing with $q.all in angular js factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

Below is the service which get the values from web api using $resource

```
(function () {
'use strict';
function a($resource) {
    return $resource('api/values/a');
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('a', ['$resource', a]);}());
```

i have a list of services like above service

below is the service which uses the above services to get the values and it will return it as single result
How can i test the below service with jasmine unit test i need code coverage for the below service

```
(function () {
'use strict';

function factoryService($q, a, b, c, d) {
    function fetch(id) {

        var data = {},
            promises = [];



        data.avalues = a.query();
        promises.push(data.avalues.$promise);

         data.bvalues = b.query();
        promises.push(data.bvalues.$promise);

        data.cvalues = c.query();
        promises.push(data.cvalues.$promise);

        data.dvalues = d.query();
        promises.push(data.dvalues.$promise);

        return $q.all(promises).then(function () {

            return data;
        });
    }

    return {
        fetch: fetch
    };
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('factoryService', ['$q', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', factoryService]);}());
```

can anyone help me to write unit test for above factory service with code coverage

describe('getting a,b,c,d values from service', function() {

```
  var service,result,httpBackend,rootScope,$q,scope;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(proposalPlanInitialData, _$httpBackend_,$rootScope, _$q_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    service = proposalPlanInitialData;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    deferred = _$q_.defer();
  }));


  it ('should be loaded', function() {
      expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  it ('should return get data when calling fetch', function() {
    fakeListing = {
    id: 123,
    price: 300000
    };
     var getData = { "id": '1', "name": "dummyvalue" };
    httpBackend.expectGET('api/values/a').respond({ "id": '1', "name": "dummyvalue" });
    httpBackend.expectGET('api/values/b').respond({ "id": '1', "name": "dummyvalue" });
    httpBackend.expectGET('api/values/c').respond({ "id": '1', "name": "dummyvalue" });
    httpBackend.expectGET('api/values/d').respond({ "id": '1', "name": "dummyvalue" });



    var data = service.fetch(1,1);

    spyOn(service, 'fetch').and.callFake(function () {
    return fakeListing;
    });        
    // httpBackend.flush();
    var data = service.fetch(1);
    expect(data).toBe(fakeListing);});});
```

but getting a data as undefined

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of questions are not welcome on StackOverflow, where you ask to do your work for you. Kindly provide your attemps to solve the problem and what went wrong, bring your question down to one specific problem, so the community could help you.

Comment: Call scope.digest() to resolve all of your promises.